# Setup initial Karate test with JUnit5 RuntimeException: not found

Tags: java, karate, junit5

I am struggling setting up a Karate Test using JUnit 5.
It's just a basic test in order to check if everything is setup fine. Unfortunately, the JUnit5 **SampleRunner** can't find my sample.feature. According to documentation and HowTo's the structure and everything should be correct. But something seems missing...

Having the following directory structure: `src/test/java` containing a `karate-config.js` and the package `utils/` with a `basic-auth.js`.

**karate-config.js:**

```
function fn() {
    var env = karate.env; // get java system property 'karate.env'
    karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
    if (!env) {
        env = 'local'; // a custom 'intelligent' default
    }
    var config = { // base config JSON
        urlBase: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    };

    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
    karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
    return config;
}
```

**basic-auth.js:**

```
function fn(creds) {
    var temp = creds.username + ':' + creds.password;
    var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
    var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(temp.getBytes());
    return 'Basic ' + encoded;
}
```

There is another package `api.sample` containing my karate-test:
**sample.feature:**

```
Feature: Sample Test

  Background:
    * url baseUrl

  Scenario: get all
    Given path "/api/sample"
    * header Authorization = call read('utils/basic-auth.js') { username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

as well as my JUnit5-Runner:

```
package api.sample;
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

public class SampleRunner {

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testSample(){
        return Karate.run("sample.feature").relativeTo(getClass());
    }
}
```

When I try to run the SampleRunner, I'm getting a

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found: api/sample/sample.feature
```

Somehow it can't find the sample.feature - and I really don't know why. Structure is set up according to your documentation...
**The pom.xml** has only this dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: sorry, screenshots don't help at all. follow this process and I'm sure it will be solved in no time: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also see: https://youtu.be/W-af7Cd8cMc - and lastly if maven + junit is too hard, consider the ZIP release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: @PeterThomas Hi, I've updated the post. Should meet the criteria now. The linked issue seems to describe a different problem, I have not problems reading from file but to make my JUnit-Runner class find the sample.feature-test.

Comment: no it doesn't. anyway, try downloading the zip from this comment and use it as a base, since you seem to be unwilling to use the quickstart: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1520#issuecomment-800002068 - if that doesn't work, I won't be able to help any more

Comment: Check that your maven contains the configuration to include test resources other than Java classes. See details here https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master#folder-structure

Comment: Hi @jramos 
Thanks for reaching out. You're absolutely right, I needed to define the testResources in my pom.xml - this was the issue,